# Proving $a\sqrt{7}>\frac{1}{c}$, where $a$ is an integer and $c = \lceil\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil-\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

> Let $a \in \Bbb{N}$, and $c=\lceil \frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil-\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}$.  Prove that $$a\sqrt{7}>\frac{1}{c}$$

So the very original problem sounds like this:

> It is given that $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$, $\sqrt{7}-\frac{a}{b}>0$. Prove that $\sqrt{7}-\frac{a}{b}>\frac{1}{ab}$.

Out of the first inequality, I expressed $b>\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}$. So I thought that the least possible value of $b$ is $\lceil\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil$. Also, I changed the inequality that I have to prove to $\frac{a^2+1}{ab}<\sqrt{7}$. I decided to change $b$ with $\lceil\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil$, so the value of $\frac{a^2+1}{ab}$ would be as big as possible. I got $\frac{a^2+1}{a\lceil\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil}<\sqrt{7}$. Then I made a $c=\lceil \frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}\rceil-\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}$. Therefore, what I had to prove was $$\frac{a^2+1}{a\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{7}}+c\right)}<\sqrt{7}$$ which is equivalent to $$a^2+1<a^2+ac\sqrt{7}$$ which is equivalent to $$a\sqrt{7}>\frac{1}{c}$$ Somehow, this inequality is not correct. If you could point me a mistake I made, I'd be insanely grateful.

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: You have to prove the inequality $ab>\frac{1}{c}$

Comment: Let's try an example...if $a=1,b=\pi-3$ then $ab=0.141592654$ and $\frac ab=7.062513306$, so $c=8-7.062513306=0.937486694$ , no?  But then $\frac 1c=1.066681806$ which is not less than $ab$.  Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I am so sorry, it was my mistake, I didn't make a very important note  $b>1$.

Comment: for $a=1;b=\sqrt{2} $ I get $a b<\frac{1}{c}$

Comment: Please check your question.  It's still easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for bothering you, I thought that general case is possible either, apparently it isn't. I just edited my question to the original one, it's been quite some time since this problem couldn't give me peace of mind until I find a solution to it.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?  We know $\{\frac ab\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$...granted, it's hard to find counterexamples here.  A fairly casual search leads us to $a=590$ since $\frac {590}{\sqrt 7}=222.9990391$ .  That's what we are looking for (that $.999$ start of the decimal that is)  but it doesn't quite make it, since in this case $ab=1560.993274$ but $\frac 1c=1040.664424$. Why do you think it is true?

Comment: Note:  If it is true, I'd imagine that continued fractions are the way to go.  That's how I found $590$.

Comment: @lulu If I put your numbers into my equation that I've got after many hours of solving this, the inequality isn't correct. Somehow, if I put it in the very very original problem, it's still correct. I can't really find a mistake that I've made.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  As a search, I am suggesting looking at the denominators of the convergents to $\frac 1{\sqrt 7}$.  use those for $a$.  They will alternate, making $\frac 1c$ very small or very large.  $590$ is the best of the small ones, but it didn't work.  I tried a few more and then stopped searching, but you should search deeper.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there's certainly a number that will make the inequality that I have, incorrect?

Comment: Oh, not at all.  I am saying that the path to understanding the question follows the line I suggested.  First thing I'd do is to search out a long those convergents.  If you get a counterexample, you are done!  If you never find one, then I would try to prove that it was true, using what we know about continued fractions.  But the search is always a good idea so I'd start there.

Comment: I believe it is critical to show that there are no solutions to $a^2-7b^2=-1$ or $a^2-7b^2=-3$.  The convergents to the continued fraction give cases where $a^2-7b^2=-3$, like $37,14$ and $82,31$.  I don't know how to do this.  Then you can write $7b^2-a^2 \ge 3,b \sqrt 7-a \ge \frac 3{b\sqrt 7+a} \gt \frac 1a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$0 <\sqrt{7} - \frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{1}{ab}$$ then (rearranging  and squaring) $$\frac{a^2}{b^2} < 7 \leq \frac{(a^2 + 1)^2}{(ab)^2}$$ or, rearranging again, $$a^2 < 7b^2 \leq a^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{a^2}.$$

If $a \neq 1$, then $a^2 < 7b^2 < a^2 + 3$, which is impossible by Ross Millikan's remark on quadratic residues modulo $7$. If $a = 1$, then the inequality becomes $1 < 7b^2 < 4$, which is also clearly impossible.

Note that this approach can be generalized to the square root of any number $n$ such that $-2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $n$ ($-1$ is never a quadratic residue).

Answer (score 1):

For the original question the critical thing to realize is that if $7b^2-a^2\gt 0$, it is at least $3$.  The squares $\bmod 7$ are $1,2,4$ which gives this, as $a^2$ cannot be $5$ or $6\  \bmod 7$

First we take care of a side case.  If $b\sqrt 7 -a \gt 1, b\sqrt 7-a \gt \frac 1a$.

Given $1 \gt b\sqrt 7-a\gt 0$ we have $$b\sqrt 7 -a \gt 0\\
7b^2-a^2 \gt 0\\7b^2-a^2 \ge 3\\b\sqrt 7-a \ge \frac 1{b\sqrt 7+a}\\
b\sqrt 7-a \gt \frac 3{2a+1}\\ b\sqrt 7 - a \gt \frac 1a\\\sqrt 7 - \frac ab \gt \frac 1{ab}$$